How can I (safely) refresh data on an HDD?
I have an HDD (for simplicity, let's assume it has a single partition).
I would like to refresh the data on my HDD: Read all data, and write the same data, possibly but not necessarily at the exact same physical location, so that the logical contents of the partition has not changed, but the data has been read and written. This is, of course, a disk maintenance operation for an archival HDD which typically sits unused.
There are a few options for doing this on Windows –
how would I go about doing this on a (modern) GNU/Linux machine?
Note:

Command-line is great, GUI is fine.
I don't mind if this requires root privileges.
I use Devuan GNU/Linux, but would rather the answer be distribution-neutral.
x86_64 machine in case it matters.
HDD is connected either via SATA, USB or PCIe. 
If your answer only regards one of these buses – that's ok.


Frame challenge: I believe that the conventional wisdom is to copy the device to a new device.   This suggests that you should back up the disk and then (perhaps after verifying the soundness of the backup) restore from it.   Restore onto the original device if you insist; at least if the process damages the disk, you still have the data.

The "non-destructive write test" of badblocks -n would seem to be exactly what you're looking for. It is filesystem-agnostic and works by reading a set of blocks into memory, writing test patterns into those same blocks, and if successful, writing the original data right back to those same blocks (as far as the OS knows; what happens on the actual media, only the HDD firmware knows for sure).
The partition must not be mounted while badblocks -n is executed on it.
Like you said, this might be an appropriate thing to do once in a while on archival HDDs in long-term storage - but like G-Man in the comments, I would emphasize not doing this to your only copy of the archived data. If badblocks -n finds a block that is just barely readable, and then it turns out it can no longer write the original data into the block after it has been replaced with test patterns, the contents of that block will be lost, as there will be no place to write it back any more.
In practice, that should only happen if the disk's internal bad block reallocation space becomes 100% full, or the disk has some catastrophic failure during the refresh - so you should also check the SMART Reallocated_Sector_Ct attribute before and after such a refresh operation.
If the raw value increases significantly during a refresh or the scaled version of the value approaches the manufacturer-specified threshold value, then that disk is clearly starting to fail and you should promptly create a new archive copy of your data on a new disk, verify it against your other copy/copies, and scrap the failing disk.

badblocks -n can also lose data if it’s interrupted. Its default 1KiB block size causes it to run painfully slowly, it’s best to increase it (-b …) but that increases the amount of data potentially lost in case of failure.

@StephenKitt I checked the source code of the current version of badblocks: it installs a signal handler, which at a quick glance seems to rewrite the data and exit gracefully if interrupted with a Control-C or a regular kill command. If interrupted with kill -9, the program obviously cannot protect itself against that.

That’s good to know, so at least users can stop it safely (as one would expect). My point was really that data loss can happen for reasons other than disk failure here — if badblocks stops in an uncontrolled fashion (it crashes itself, or the system crashes), data can be lost. It’s another argument in favour of backups ;-).

You also have to consider other factors, like cable issues or power loss. I see badblocks as one of the riskier options since it does deliberately write wrong data after all. With other tools, among your biggest risks is bad ram... if the memory used for the internal buffer happens to be bad then it will corrupt the entire drive :-) in the end it all depends on how strongly you interpret "safely". Touching the data at all is a risk in and of itself...

Also for obvious reasons the device should be used exclusively (not mount while rewriting).
